# How to pass more parameters in array_map function Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I want to pass more parameters in this function:

```
$option1=$res['attributes'][0]['option'];
$option2=$res['attributes'][1]['option'];
$row['variations'] = array_map(function($var) {
return ['id' => $var];}
,$row['variations']);
```

Now, I am able only to pass $var, and I want to have

```
['id' => $var,
 'option1'=>$option1,
 'option2'=>$option2]
```

This is my response now:

```
 0 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 3095
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 3096
  ]
```

And I need something like

```
 0 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 3095,
    "option1"=>"Blue",
    "option2"=>"M"

  ]
```

Comment: try array_map(function() use($var,$option1,$option2){

Comment: You can find more information and example from docs for your queston https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information and example from docs
php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
$option1=$res['attributes'][0]['option'];
$option2=$res['attributes'][1]['option'];
$row['variations'] = array_map(null, $option1,$option2)
```